# JSON Array exception using json string field

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, json

I am trying to create a JSONArray object and in the JSONArray there is another array which contains an object that is a json string as below. Note the res field.

```
[{
    "time": 123813213,
    "value": [{
        "name": "task",
        "res": "{\"taskName\" : \"NAME\", \"taskValue\" : 3}"
    }]
}]
```

This causes an exception when I return the above as a String and do

```
String jsonStr = "[{ \"time\": 123813213, \"value\": [{ \"name\": \"task\", \"res\": \"{\"taskName\", \"taskValue\"}\" }] }]";

JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
```

The problem is fixed when I do this by adding additional \ where the json string that I am storing is located.

```
String jsonStr = "[{ \"time\": 123813213, \"value\": [{ \"name\": \"task\", \"res\": \"{\\\"taskName\\\", \\\"taskValue\"}\\\" }] }]";

JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
```

Note the additional \ that I added. I am not sure how to fix the first case as I am not creating the jsonStr myself but instead getting it from somewhere and it only contains one \ not three \. Is there something I am doing wrong in the first case?

The exception I get is this using the first example

```
org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at 61 [character 62 line 1]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:432)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:223)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:362)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:117)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:365)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:208)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:362)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:117)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:145)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

The second example parses fine and returns the correct result which is this.

```
[{"time":123813213,"value":[{"res":"{\"taskName\", \"taskValue\"}","name":"task"}]}]
```

Question is how do I get the first example to return this?

Answer (score 1):

The first case should be fine. Since you're getting it from an external source you don't have to add extra backslashes to escape characters. But when you *manually* type out a string literal in your code it requires adding backslashes to escape certain characters.

Note that `"{\"taskName\", \"taskValue\"}"` is invalid JSON. If it could be parsed it would result in `{"taskName", "taskValue"}` which isn't valid syntax in javascript. To create an array you would use `["taskName", "taskValue"]`.

If you meant for it to be an object it would be something like `{"taskName": "Wash dishes", "taskValue": 5}`

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't put the entire json and I fixed it to make it valid.

The thing is the first one does not work. It returns an exception.

 "res": "{\"taskName\" : \"NAME\", \"taskValue\" : 3}"

I think the reason is it is treating taskName and taskValue as json objects but they are not. I want to keep the entire value of res as a String. How do I fix that?

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice at first, but it's because `JSONArray` only accepts JSON arrays but you're passing it a JSON object.

Comment: Why does the second case work then? I am trying to pass the json object as a string not a json object (referring to the res field).

Comment: My mistake. I was just thinking of `res` not being a JSON array when I wrote that and I misunderstood your question. Taking another look.

Comment: Hmm. The first example parses just fine for me. How does it get from there to the written-out `jsonStr` string in the second example?

Comment: Hmm, the first example parsed fine for you? I just copy pasted the first example and resulted in the exception I posted above. The second example parsed fine for me. I don't quite follow your question sorry. They are two separate examples the second one parse fine but not the first one.

Comment: Ah, that's what it is. You can't just copy and paste (or type) a string that has characters that need to be escaped. `"` and `\\` characters, among others, will need a backslash added in front to mean the same thing when *written out in code*. If the first example is going straight into a variable from another source you don't have to do this. It'll just work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please share the exception. It is a valid JSON, it should work.

The second one is working because when you convert a JSON to a String in JAVA it is created as this.

"[{\"time\":123813213,\"value\":[{\"name\":\"task\",\"res\":\"{\\"taskName\\" : \\"NAME\\", \\"taskValue\\" : 3}\"}]}]"

You can try this by using any JSON to String converter in java.
There is nothing wrong with your json.

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at 61 [character 62 line 1]
 at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:432)
 at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:223)
 at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:362)
 at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:117)
 at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:365)
 at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:208)
 at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:362)
 at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:117)
 at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:145)
 at Main.main(Main.java:10)